# question about derivative with respect to the log of the parameter

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a function $K(\phi)$ and I need to compute $\frac{dK}{d \log(\phi)}$.

I am guessing I can break this as:

$$
\frac{dK}{d \log(\phi)} = \frac{dK}{d\phi} \frac{d \phi}{d \log(\phi)}
= \frac{dK}{d\phi} \phi
$$

Is what I have done correct? I am not sure if I can write $\frac{d \phi}{d \log(\phi)} = \phi$

Comment: Its correct without any ambiguities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is correct. You could write $\psi=\ln(\phi)$, so $e^\psi=\phi$, and you have
\begin{equation}
K(\phi)=K(e^\psi)=\tilde{K}(\psi)
\end{equation}
so your derivative would look like
\begin{equation}
\frac{dK(\phi)}{d\ln(\phi)}=\frac{d\tilde{K}(\psi)}{d\psi}=\frac{dK(e^\psi)}{d\psi}=K'(e^\psi)\cdot e^\psi=K'(\phi)\cdot\phi
\end{equation}